# Customize list view group short name style

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

How can one customize the grouped short name in the right side of the list view? Does anyone have an idea about the list view custom renderer?

Following expected output

[image]

Comment: Are you using xamarin forms or Xamarin iOS?

Comment: xamarin forms@z

Comment: please look at my answere

Comment: @Riyas Did you got the answer

Comment: @AswathyKR Yes, the first answer below was worked.

Comment: @Riyas both android and iOS

Comment: @AswathyKR Oops, I have only implemented in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official Documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/tables/populating-a-table-with-data/),refer to **Adding an index**

Sample [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/WorkingWithTables/), refer to **BasicTableIndex**

**Steps**:

- **create the short name Arrays by the dataSource.**

  ```
  indexedTableItems = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
  foreach (var t in items) {
      if (indexedTableItems.ContainsKey (t[0].ToString ())) {
          indexedTableItems[t[0].ToString ()].Add(t);
      } else {
          indexedTableItems.Add (t[0].ToString (), new List<string>() {t});
      }
  }
  keys = indexedTableItems.Keys.ToArray ();
  ```
- **display the sections by overriding these methods**

  ```
  public override nint NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
  {
  return keys.Length;
  }
  public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, nint section)
  {
     return indexedTableItems[keys[section]].Count;
  }
  public override string[] SectionIndexTitles (UITableView tableView)
  {
     return keys;
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi, I need to change the color of the alphabets right side of the screenshot is there any ways to modify that? @cole xia

Comment: @Riyas  of course, use :  table.SectionIndexColor = UIColor.Red;   and it is available after iOS 6.0

Comment: table.SectionIndexColor = UIColor.Red; 
cool,it works. And thanks for your quick response though @cole xia

Answer (score 0):

No need to create render for that

Please try below code pattern

Your xaml code look like

```
<ListView x:Name ="lstView" IsGroupingEnabled="true" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding LongName}" GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding ShortName}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate><TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail = "{Binding Comment}" /></DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Your xaml.cs page look like

```
private ObservableCollection<GroupedVeggieModel> grouped { get; set; }
        public GroupedListXaml ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            grouped = new ObservableCollection<GroupedVeggieModel> ();
            var veggieGroup = new GroupedVeggieModel () { LongName = "vegetables", ShortName="v" };
            var fruitGroup = new GroupedVeggieModel () { LongName = "fruit", ShortName = "f" };
            veggieGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () { Name = "celery", IsReallyAVeggie = true, Comment = "try ants on a log" });
            veggieGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () { Name = "tomato", IsReallyAVeggie = false, Comment = "pairs well with basil" });
            veggieGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () { Name = "zucchini", IsReallyAVeggie = true, Comment = "zucchini bread > bannana bread" });
            veggieGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () { Name = "peas", IsReallyAVeggie = true, Comment = "like peas in a pod" });
            fruitGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () {Name = "banana", IsReallyAVeggie = false,Comment = "available in chip form factor"});
            fruitGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () {Name = "strawberry", IsReallyAVeggie = false,Comment = "spring plant"});
            fruitGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () {Name = "cherry", IsReallyAVeggie = false,Comment = "topper for icecream"});
            grouped.Add (veggieGroup); grouped.Add (fruitGroup);
            lstView.ItemsSource = grouped;
        }
```

Your Model look like

```
public class VeggieModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public bool IsReallyAVeggie { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public VeggieModel ()
        {
        }
    }

    public class GroupedVeggieModel : ObservableCollection<VeggieModel>
    {
        public string LongName { get; set; }
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
    }
```

Source code [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/ListView/Grouping)

Comment: FYI i figured it to do group short name , now i need to change the color of the alphabets is there any chance to do it here?@ziyad